# ZXing-minimal - scan only when button pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

Is there some simple way to use ZXing-minimal to make a fragment with barcode scanner, which will scan only when I press button somewhere in activity(can be a button in the fragment)? I want to make a fragment at the top with preview of camera, then button "scan" in the middle and list of scanned items at the bottom. I already used ZXing to make a scan activity but it scans all the time, and I would like to make it scan only when I press button. If the button is not pressed I just want to see the preview of the camera so I can point on the specified barcode and then press scan to scan it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 
https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

This would help you with `CompoundBarcodeView`.